# Credible Modern Videos/Stories of Buddhist Six Paranormal Powers

Tags: modern-world, psychic-powers

Buddha and others repeatedly says that those that have genuine samadhi can easily cultivate the Six Paranormal Powers--if they have not experienced them by accident already. The Path of Purification even outlines the step-by-step method to cultivate them after obtaining concentration attainment.

In the Taoist tradition there are plenty of stories of such immortals and super-powered people, some of them even very modern, such as the [Youtube video of John Chang emitting fire through his hands](http://blog.asiantown.net/-/9042/indonesian-man-burns-paper-with-the-electric-power-inside-his-body.aspx). [The books that are based on him are very awesome and interesting, like The Magus of Java.]

**What are some modern accounts in the Buddhist tradition?**

When I meet Buddhist people and others, they often say they have samadhi but they seem quite ordinary to me. Oftentimes, I am convinced that they make claims of samadhi merely to gain a following--however small it may be.

Answer (score 3):

The Buddha forbade monks to demonstrate psychic powers to lay people. Therefore, at least in Theravada Buddhism, it is uncommon to meet Buddhists claiming & displaying psychic powers.

The monks rules state:

> 8. Should any bhikkhu report (his own) superior human state to an unordained person, when it is factual, it is to be confessed.
>      Displaying psychic powers. A related rule at Cv.V.8.2 states that to
>      display psychic powers to lay people is a dukkata [offense].
>
> > [Page 263 to 266](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc1.pdf)

Psychic powers are said to occur only in individuals with a latent pre-disposition. For example, many arahants, such as Venerable Sariputta, a jhana master, did not have supernormal powers.

Therefore, the Buddha could not have repeatedly said that [all of] those that have genuine samadhi can easily cultivate the Six Paranormal Powers. In the [Susima Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.070.than.html), it is reported the Buddha explains to Susima that development of psychic powers is not a prerequisite for enlightenment.

Therefore, suttas such as [Kayagata-sati Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html) (quoted below) that generalise about samadhi & powers are probably fake.

> Monks, for one in whom mindfulness immersed in the body is
>   cultivated, developed, pursued, handed the reins and taken as a basis,
>   given a grounding, steadied, consolidated, & well-undertaken, ten
>   benefits can be expected. Which ten?
>
> [5] "He wields manifold supranormal powers. Having been one he becomes
>   many; having been many he becomes one. He appears. He vanishes. He
>   goes unimpeded through walls, ramparts, & mountains as if through
>   space. He dives in & out of the earth as if it were water. He walks on
>   water without sinking as if it were dry land. Sitting crosslegged he
>   flies through the air like a winged bird. With his hand he touches &
>   strokes even the sun & moon, so mighty & powerful. He exercises
>   influence with his body even as far as the Brahma worlds.
>
> [6] "He hears — by means of the divine ear-element, purified &
>   surpassing the human — both kinds of sounds: divine & human, whether
>   near or far.
>
> [7] "He knows the mind of other beings, other individuals, having
>   encompassed it with his own mind....

The Buddha himself did not think highly of psychic powers ([Kevatta Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than.html)) despite often using psychic powers to only help monks with their practise (example, [Sona Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.055.than.html)).

We must also understand the Buddha's enemies, such as Devadatta & Mara, had psychic powers.

In summary, psychic powers are 100% unrelated to the goal of Buddhism.